# How to detect how long a button was pressed in Arduino?

Tags: c, arduino, atmega

How can I detect how long a button was pressed / released in Arduino and then print some custom output after that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Arduino can only detect the state of your button (pressed OR unpressed).

You could use a timer variable (based on [this example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ButtonStateChange) from their docs) to save the exact time when you **pressed** or **released** the button, so you can check the difference between both variables to calculate how long it is on hold or idle.

The code could look like this:

```c
const int buttonPin = 2;  

int buttonState = 0;     // current state of the button
int lastButtonState = 0; // previous state of the button
int startPressed = 0;    // the moment the button was pressed
int endPressed = 0;      // the moment the button was released
int holdTime = 0;        // how long the button was hold
int idleTime = 0;        // how long the button was idle

void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT); // initialize the button pin as a input
  Serial.begin(9600);        // initialize serial communication
}

void loop() {
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin); // read the button input

  if (buttonState != lastButtonState) { // button state changed
     updateState();
  }

  lastButtonState = buttonState;        // save state for next loop
}

void updateState() {
  // the button has been just pressed
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
      startPressed = millis();
      idleTime = startPressed - endPressed;

      if (idleTime >= 500 && idleTime < 1000) {
          Serial.println("Button was idle for half a second");
      }

      if (idleTime >= 1000) {
          Serial.println("Button was idle for one second or more"); 
      }

  // the button has been just released
  } else {
      endPressed = millis();
      holdTime = endPressed - startPressed;

      if (holdTime >= 500 && holdTime < 1000) {
          Serial.println("Button was held for half a second"); 
      }

      if (holdTime >= 1000) {
          Serial.println("Button was held for one second or more"); 
      }

  }
}
```

However, if you want to trigger an event **while** the button is still pressed (or maybe you want to increment a counter in some display), you can still do the same math.

Change your condition in the loop function to be like this:

```c
  if (buttonState != lastButtonState) { 
     updateState(); // button state changed. It runs only once.
  } else {
     updateCounter(); // button state not changed. It runs in a loop.
  }
```

And then implement your new function like this:

```
void updateCounter() {
  // the button is still pressed
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
      holdTime = millis() - startPressed;

      if (holdTime >= 1000) {
          Serial.println("Button is held for more than a second"); 
      }

  // the button is still released
  } else {
      idleTime = millis() - endPressed;

      if (idleTime >= 1000) {
          Serial.println("Button is released for more than a second");  
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for your interest here's an example of code using 2 arrays to store button states of arduino pin  given to the corresponding input button. During the loop you can do a simple check with the wanted repeat:

```
  if(button_down(But1_pin, BTN_LOOP_DELAY_MS))
  {
    // code here repeated if the button is either clicked or maintained
  }
```

`button_down()` also defers the first repeat by `DELAY_WAIT_BEFORE_REPEAT` ms.

Here the full tested example:

```
#define BTN_LOOP_DELAY_MS   100
#define DELAY_WAIT_BEFORE_REPEAT  500
#define NB_MAX_PIN_INPUT    13

#define But1_pin    7
#define But2_pin    6

// array to check status change
bool prev_button[NB_MAX_PIN_INPUT];
unsigned long button_last_down[NB_MAX_PIN_INPUT];

// macro : our read init with prev_button storage
#define READ_INIT_BUTTON(pin)  \
  do{ \
    pinMode(pin, INPUT); \
    prev_button[pin] = digitalRead(pin); \
   } while(false)

// function at the end of the code
bool button_down(byte pin_num, unsigned int delay_repeated);

void setup() {
  READ_INIT_BUTTON(But1_pin);
  READ_INIT_BUTTON(But2_pin);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  if(button_down(But1_pin, BTN_LOOP_DELAY_MS))
  {
    Serial.print("new inpulse");
    Serial.print(millis());
    Serial.println();
  }

  if(button_down(But2_pin, BTN_LOOP_DELAY_MS))
  {
    Serial.println("button2");
  }

}

bool button_down(byte pin_num, unsigned int delay_repeated)
{
  bool b = digitalRead(pin_num);
  bool r = false;

  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if(prev_button[pin_num] != HIGH && b == HIGH)
  {
    r = true;
    button_last_down[pin_num] = currentMillis + DELAY_WAIT_BEFORE_REPEAT;
  }
  else if(b == HIGH 
      && prev_button[pin_num] == HIGH
      && currentMillis > button_last_down[pin_num] 
      && currentMillis - button_last_down[pin_num] > delay_repeated
    )
  {
    // save the last time we give a button impusle at true
    button_last_down[pin_num] = currentMillis;
    r = true;
  }

  // store button state, if changed
  if(prev_button[pin_num] != b)
  {
    prev_button[pin_num] = b;
  }
    
  return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This following steps works:

- If the button state satisfies.
- Then read the millis() values one time(Using flag) and find the
  duration by comparing with current millis() value.

  ```
    void buttonLongPress() {
     uint32_t duration = 0;

     if (digitalRead(button_pin) == LOW) {
       if (pressReadLimit == 0) {
         pressTime = millis();
         pressReadLimit = 1;
       }
       duration = millis() - pressTime;
       if (duration >= 3000) {
         Serial.println("Long press");
       }
       Serial.println(duration);
     } else {
       duration = 0;
       pressReadLimit = 0;
     }
   }
  ```

[Serial monitor result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWfjJ.png)